# Is the relation correct?

Tags: calculus

Accoeding to my notes:

$\sum_{n=1} ^{m} z^n=z+z^2+....=\frac{1}{1-z}(z(1-z)+z^2(1-z)+....+z^m(1-z))=\frac{z(1-z^m)}{1-z}, |z|<1$,so $\lim_{m \to +\infty} z^m=0$,therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} z^n=\frac{z}{1-z}$

Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: The first equality is wrong. The last one is correct.

Comment: Isn't it like that : $$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$$ ?

Comment: No, $\sum \limits_{n=\color{red}0}^{+\infty} z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$.